# Вопрос, который дубликат вопроса, который объединён с этим же вопросом?

Tags: дефект, дубликаты

Есть два вопроса, допустим, [вопрос 1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/988427) и [вопрос 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/992085). Модератор объединил вопрос 1 с вопросом 2, вследствие чего вопрос 1 закрылся, а потом сообщество отметило вопрос 2 дубликатом вопроса 1. Это вообще, блин, как, если вопросы уже и так объединены? Баг движка сайта? Теперь в обоих вопросах нельзя писать ответы, потому что движок считает их дубликатами друг друга (обожаю циклические зависимости).

Comment: Видимо, сообщество руководствовалось датой создания, а модератор наличием ответа

Comment: То, что это возможно — [баг](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232442/merged-question-is-closed-as-a-duplicate-of-itself). А случилось из-за того, что последние закрыватели либо были невнимательны, либо указали другую причину закрытия (не дубликат). В любом случае понятно что нужно делать если вопрос нужно открыть: голосовать за переоткрытие и ставить особую тревогу для модератора.

Answer (score 2):

1. Дата при объединения не особо важна.
2. Пришлось объединить в более поздний вопрос, т.к. там был ответ. Модераторы не могут ответы переносить =/
3. Я видел на целевом вопросе вчера 4 голоса за закрытие и взял вопрос на контроль. Если бы его закрыли, я бы его потом открыл.
4. В целом, никакого бага нет. Но вот то, что последний закрывающий не посмотрел контекст полный - не очень хорошо, хоть и простительно.
5. Но возможно я объединил не в ту сторону      (｡•́︿•̀｡)

P.S. вопрос переоткрыт.

Comment: Так то есть баг. Вопрос 1 закрыт с причиной "Непонятна суть вопроса", но при этом объединен с другим вопросом. Объединенный вопрос должен быть закрыт как дубликат, а не с левой причиной: `In order to merge a question, the question to be merged must first be closed as a duplicate of the intended merge target.` https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question

Comment: При объединении вопросов все ответы и комментарии переносятся. Ну, [почти все](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8941/178988).

Comment: @Qwertiy в след. раз заострю внимание на этом. Механизм какой-то неоднозначный. В случае с объединением меток система хотя бы показывает предварительно, что будет в результате, а тут нет =/

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight  странно всё это